# How to get following output with these lists in Python?

Tags: python, list

```
list1 =[(18.6, 11.6), (40.6, 6.4), (13.0, 7.0), (20.4, 3.2), (22.0, 9.0)]
list2 =[0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Output: using list1 and list2:

```
list3 = [18.6, 6.4, 7.0, 3.2, 9.0]
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is very poor quality. Take the [tour], read about [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can zip the lists and loop through them in a list comprehension:

```py
list3 = [x[y] for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Comment: This works perfectly, output: `[18.6, 6.4, 7.0, 3.2, 9.0]` - I have no idea why it's been downvoted.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I can imagine the reason for the downvote. The answer is correct, but answering questions that show no effort to solve the problem attract more bad questions (and we don't really need those here).